# how to check multiple strings for emptyness in python

Tags: python

I have inputs `s1`, `s2`, `s3`. I need to concatenate them only if they really exist.

I did:

```
s1 = s1.strip()
s2 = s2.strip()
s3 = s3.strip()
if s1 and s2 and s3: 
   input = s1 + ' ' + s2 + ' ' + s3
if s1 and s2:
   input = s1 + ' ' + s2
if s1 and s3: 
   input = s1 + ' ' + s3
if s2 and s3: 
   input = s2 + ' ' + s3
....
...
```

e.g. I dont want `test  ( white  space )`. I want `test` if the rest 2 inputs are empty.

how can I do this in more efficient and elegant way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `join()` to join non-empty strings (one line):

```
>>> s1 = 'test'
>>> s2 = ''
>>> s3 = ''
>>> ' '.join(s for s in (s1,s2,s3) if s)
'test'
```

Comment: +1. Though it's quicker if you use a list comprehension inside `join` as [per this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-python)